# Can't find module using fastAPI - Uvicorn

Tags: python, import, fastapi

I have a python file named `twitter_spider.py` in which other files are **imported** from the `core` *directory* on it and it works well.

[image: files Structure]

I am going to read that file in the ***router file*** `route.py`, which has the task of connecting functions to routes in fastapi, but when I run the project using ***Uvicorn***, it says that the `core` module was not recognized and the error originates from the `twitter_spider.py`.

I'm really confused why there is no problem without running **Uvicorn**, but by adding the `twitter_spider` file to the `route.py` file, the `twitter_spider` file becomes a problem.
I use this command to run server:

```
uvicorn main:app --reload
```

**Error** :

```
File "/--/services/twitter_spider.py", line 1, in <module>
from core import Twitter_Conecction
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core'
```

My `route.py` code is :

```
from fastapi import APIRouter
from models.twitter import Twitter
from config.database import collection
from schema.schemas import list_serialize
from services.twitter_spider import ACCOUNT, USERNAME, PASSWORD
from bson import ObjectId

router = APIRouter()

# GET Request Methods


@router.get('/')
async def get_account_information():
    # info = list_serialize(collection.find())
    ACCOUNT.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
    info = ACCOUNT.me
    return info
```

And that's my `twitter_spider.py` code:
its login in *twitter* and return user information.

```
from core import Twitter_Conecction
from core import config

USERNAME = 'jj'
EMAIL = 'jj@jj.com'
PASSWORD = 'jj'
config.PROXY = {"http": "127.0.0.1:2080", "https": "127.0.0.1:2080"}
ACCOUNT = Twitter_Conecction()


def main():
    ACCOUNT.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
    print(ACCOUNT.me)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This works well, but when it is combined with ***fastapi***, it has problems.

Answer (score 0):

You should create `__init__.py` in `services` and all the other "subdirectories" (= modules) in your project. You only have `__init__.py` in `core`, which is not sufficient for what you're trying to achieve.